# Fortran compiler not found when configuring

Tags: configure, intel-fortran, waf

I am trying to install some code on my Mac (10.15.7). I follow the instructions and do

`./waf configure --install_all_deps`

But I get

```
No suitable fortran compiler found (cause: 'cannot determine ifort version.
(complete log in /Users/joe/Documents/Research/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/build/config.log)') 
The configuration failed
(complete log in /Users/joe/Documents/Research/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/build/config.log)
```

`which ifort` gives

`/usr/local/bin/ifort`

And `ifort -v` gives

`ifort version 19.1.1.216`

The last part of the referenced config.log is

```
Checking for program 'ifort'
/opt/anaconda3/envs/py38/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-gfortran
find program=['ifort'] paths=['/opt/anaconda3/envs/py38/bin', '/opt/anaconda3/condabin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin', '/usr/local/bin', '/opt/local/bin', '/Users/joe/Documents/Research/openmpi-3.0.0/oshmem/mca/scoll/mpi/bin', '/opt/local/bin', '/opt/local/sbin', '/usr/local/bin', '/usr/bin', '/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/sbin', '/Library/TeX/texbin', '/Library/Apple/usr/bin'] var='FC' -> ['/opt/anaconda3/envs/py38/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-gfortran']
['/opt/anaconda3/envs/py38/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-gfortran', '-logo']
err: ld: library not found for -logo
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

from /Users/joe/Documents/Research/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01: cannot determine ifort version.
from /Users/joe/Documents/Research/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01: The configuration failed
```

Answer (score 2):

the log says different things:

- waf looked for `ifort` in your default paths:

  - `/opt/anaconda3/envs/py38/bin`
  - `/opt/anaconda3/condabin`
  - `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin`
  - `/usr/local/bin`
  - `/opt/local/bin`
  - [...]
- waf has found a fortran compiler, actually `/opt/anaconda3/envs/py38/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-gfortran`, but when executing it, it can't find a library, `libogo`. It found it at the wrong place, because `/usr/local/bin` is after
  `/opt/anaconda3/envs/py38/bin` in the paths list.

To change the paths list, you can use the parameter `path_list` of the `find_program` function in the waf file named `wscript`.

But a simpler way is probably to change the PATH when calling `waf`:

```sh
PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" ./waf configure --install_all_deps
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not familiar with these parameters, could you elaborate how to use them? For example I get `zsh: command not found: find_program` when I try it in terminal, so I am not sure where to use this. Maybe in the Makefile?

Comment: No it's a parameter to a function call in the file read by waf, a file named `wscript`. waf seems to find a fortran compiler, but not the right one. If you don't want to modify the wscript, you can use `PATH`. I will edit my answer